# Add subheaders to groups of facets using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use "facet_wrap" to have several violin plots in one plot. I have 2 groups of variables, one is "color" and then within each color, there are different "groups". When I do the following, I can almost get what I want:

sample data:

```
score<-c(1:10,1:10,1:10,1:10,1:10,1:10,1:10,1:10,1:10,1:10,1:10,1:10)
  

color<-c("white","white","white","white","white","white","white","white","white","white","white","white","white","white","white","white","white","white","white","white","white","white","white","white","white","white","white","white","white","white","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","black","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","grey","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown","brown")

group<-c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","D","E","E","E","E","E","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","H","I","I","I","I","I","I","I","I","I","I","I","I","I","I","I")


animal<-c("dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","dog","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","cat","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny","bunny")


df<-tibble(animal,score,group,color)
```

making the plot:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=animal,y=score,fill=animal)) + 
geom_violin()+  
facet_wrap(color ~ group)+
theme_clean()
```

[image]

However, I would like all of the plots with the same value for "color" to be on the same line, and for it to just say the name of each color once, like as a subheading, at the top of that group of letters(instead of above each letter). Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: The data you provided above doesn't have the column `category`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the layout of the plot in advance, you can use `ggh4x::facet_manual()`. Disclaimer: I'm the author of ggh4x.

```r
score  <- rep(1:10, 12)
color  <- rep(c("white", "black", "grey", "brown"), each = 30)
group  <- rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"),
              c(15, 15, 16, 9, 5, 15, 15, 15, 15))
animal <- rep(c("dog", "cat", "bunny"), c(39, 46, 35))

df <- data.frame(animal, score, group, color)

library(ggh4x)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

layout <- "
ABC
DE#
FG#
HI#
"
ggplot(df, aes(animal, score, fill = animal)) +
  geom_violin() +
  facet_manual(
    vars(color, group),
    design = layout,
    strip  = strip_nested()
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Very cool package, thanks! Is it possible to make the titles of each group bold? @teunbrand

Comment: Yeah you can use `strip_nested(text_x = elem_list_text(face = c("bold", "plain")), by_layer_x = TRUE)` instead of the `strip_nested()`.

Comment: Do you know why strip_nested() would be giving the error "Error in as.numeric(x) : cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'double'" @teunbrand

Comment: I might if I knew what is the input.